# Frame segmentation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am very new to computer vision.
And I'm learning to implement a real time tracking programme
When I use colour segmentation, which is ,accessing every pixels and threshold the image according to a condition like R<128 G<128 B<128
The result segmented from the frame is good but the frame rate is becoming low

So I want to ask is that common to process each frame like this or there are some algorithms and techniques?

Comment: This looks like a common performance issue. It's normal for the FPS to drop. Your code has a performance limitation.

Comment: It also depends on what library/platform you're using, as well as how you're coding the thresholding.  Are you using OpenCV? MATLAB? OpenCV has the `inRange` function that takes in a threshold per channel.  MATLAB can perform this using `logical` operators.  These both have very efficient methods for thresholding frames.  Doing it yourself with a pair of `for` loops is probably the most inefficient way and that's also a reason why your frame rate could drop.

Comment: @rayryeng thank you, it really helps, I will try to use inRange function

Comment: @ChengMa - http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange - Look at the documentation.  For your purposes, the lower bound is 0 and the upper bound is 128 for all channels.